# Scheme making matrix

Tags: matrix, scheme, racket

I am new to scheme and I'm having problems with matrices in Scheme. I need to create a function that takes one big and one small square matrices (with the condition: the small's length should be divisor of big one) and make a new matrix with doing an operation on the big one with small one. I've successfully split the big matrix to size that I wanted and I’m successfully operating on it to get the result.

Here is how I did it:

```
(define (matrix-op big small x y)
    (if (< y (/ (length big) (length small))))
        (if (< x (/ (length big) (length small)))
            (cons (calculate (split-y (split-x big small x) small y) small)
                  (matrix-op big small (+ x 1) y)) 
            (matrix-op big small 0 (+ y 1)) ; <- this is where i need to split
        )
        '()
    )
)
```

My calculate function returns only 1 atomic value so when I run the function like this it gives me an output like '(val val val val), but what i want is formatting the output like '((val val) (val val)). How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

---

I realized that I couldn't explain the problem properly. What i want to have is a function that takes two different square matrices one big and one small, Splits the big one to same size as smaller one, operates on them to create a new matrix that has the size m/n if the big one is mxm and small one is nxn. Example:

```
big '(                       small '(
(8 0 3 1 5 3 2 2)                    (8 4)
(7 1 1 4 3 7 1 4)                    (9 5)
(1 3 7 4 3 6 6 3)                    )
(0 9 8 6 5 6 4 3)
(1 7 6 9 6 6 7 2)
(5 7 1 0 2 9 5 3)
(0 5 4 6 6 6 3 0)
(3 6 2 7 7 5 7 0)
)
```

I need to split big over the same size as small and calculate results like:

```
for x=0 y=0 part is '(       calculate result is 5
                      (8 0)
                      (7 1)
                      )

for x=1 y=0 part is '(       calculate result is 2
                      (3 1)
                      (1 4)
                      )
```

I actually did returned the results calculated but with the method i gave above my return was like `'(5 2 4 2 2 6 4 4 4 3 5 4 2 4 6 3)` but I wanted to return as:

```
'(
  (5 2 4 2) 
  (2 6 4 4) 
  (4 3 5 4) 
  (2 4 6 3)
 )
```

So how can I manage to split the return list where i want to split?

Comment: Please provide a sample input and the expected output of the procedure

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I gave a sample input and output. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do too much at once. It is always OK to split a bigger problem into a smaller problem.

If I understand yours, the idea is to take two square matrics, one of which may be some multiple of the other’s dimensions, and perform a pair-wise operation on the elements. For example:

```
'((1 2 3)                 '((1 2 3)   '((7 7 7)       '(( 8  9 10)
  (4 5 6)  + '((7))  -->    (4 5 6)  +  (7 7 7)   -->   (11 12 13)
  (7 8 9))                  (7 8 9))    (7 7 7))        (14 15 16))
```

I will continue with the assumption that this is what is desired.

Notice that if the two matrices were the same size, a simple nested `map` would easily combine all elements. What is left is the problem of the different sizes.
Solve that and you are golden.

Recap:

```
(define (f op small-M big-M)
  (f-apply-pairwise-op 
    op
    (f-biggify small-M (/ (length big-M) (length small-M)))
    big-M))
```

Now you have broken the problem into two smaller pieces:

```
(define (f-apply-pairwise-op op A B) ...)  ; produces pairwise 'A op B'

(define (f-biggify M n) ...)  ; tile M n times wider and taller
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realized that my problem was not explained properly above, As you said i needed to operate on matrices with different sizes but i also need to make a matrix that has a different size i'll extend the question now.